# Updating Redux State from response data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web, redux

I have a login/signup system for my React App.

I want to set the `user` state to the response recieved after `fetch`. The code looks like this -

```
export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    user: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      fetch("http://localhost:5000/user/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(action.payload),
      })
        .then((res) => {
          return res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          state.user = data;
        });
    },
  },
});
```

Everything works fine until I add the line `state.user = data` , after which I get an error which says -

**Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot perform 'set' on a proxy that has been revoked**

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to directly alter the state. A reducer is a function `(state, action) => newState` in which you have to return the new state without altering the old state.

For example: `return {...state, user: data }`

But there is an alternative you could check out: [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction), which let's you change a cloned state draft.

But another problem here is, that you should not fetch the data inside your reducer. The so called side effects like fetching data should be outside.

[redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) is a good framework to do this.